# Control structures (IF/ELSE)

Tags: oracle, variables, if-statement, sqlplus

I try to create plsql block but it doesnt work. Oracle says that i have error at line 2. I think it could be because substitution variable is not placed right !?

```
DECLARE
V_ENAME EMPLOYEES.LAST_NAME%TYPE := '&LNAME';
V_SAL EMPLOYEES.SALARY%TYPE;
BEGIN
SELECT LAST_NAME, SALARY
INTO V_ENAME, V_SAL
FROM employees WHERE LAST_NAME = V_ENAME;
IF V_SAL < 3000 THEN
v_sal := v_sal + 500;
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE (v_ename || 'have increasement ');
ELSIF V_SAL > 3000 THEN
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE (v_ename || 'do not have increasement ');
ELSE
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ('error');
END IF;
END;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since there can be many employees with the last name passed by the user, you may use an implicit `CURSOR FOR LOOP`. Also, add `first_name` in the output for clarity.

```
DECLARE
     v_ename employees.last_name%TYPE := '&LNAME';
     v_sal employees.salary%TYPE;
BEGIN

for rec IN ( SELECT first_name,last_name,salary
    FROM employees WHERE last_name = v_ename
) 
 LOOP

   IF rec.salary < 3000 THEN
     v_sal := rec.salary + 500;
     dbms_output.put_line (rec.first_name||' '||rec.last_name ||  
                         ' has an increase');
   ELSIF rec.salary  > 3000  THEN 
     dbms_output.put_line (rec.first_name||' '||rec.last_name || 
                         ' does not have an increase ');

   ELSE dbms_output.put_line ('error');
  END IF;
 END LOOP;
END;
/
```

Execution

```
..
old:DECLARE
     v_ename employees.last_name%TYPE := '&LNAME';
..
new:DECLARE
     v_ename employees.last_name%TYPE := 'Grant';

..


Douglas Grant has an increase
Kimberely Grant does not have an increase 


PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it's your problem but there is really no need to select last_name into v_ename when you are already ensuring last_name is equal to v_ename in the where clause.

Comment: Thank you, but it doesnt work... It also displays "no data found at line 5"

Comment: 1.I have to declare variable "V_SAL" to save salary of employee;
2.Last name of employee have to be saved into substitution variable;
3.When we enter "Last name" of employee, his salary have to be saved into "V_SAL";